# Есть ли в Qt что-то наподобие Flyout (UWP/WinUI3)

Tags: c++, qt

В WinUI 3 или в UWP есть очень удобный control Flyout. Например, при нажатии на кнопку выпадает всплывающий элемент, который содержит в себе все возможное. Очень удобная вещь. Есть ли такое в Qt? Я нашел QToolButton. Может в нем можно такое реализовать?

Comment: при нажатии кнопки открываете форму без рамок где надо и помещаете туда "все возможное"